# regex year format authentication

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a program where the user is asked for the session year which needs to be in the form of 20XX-20XX. The constraint here is that it needs to be a year followed by its next year. Eg. 2019-2020.

For example,
**Vaild Formats:**

```
2019-2020
2018-2019
2000-2001
```

**Invalid Fromats:**

```
2019-2021
2000-2000
2019-2018
```

I am trying to validate this input using regular expressions.

**My work:**

```
import re

def add_pages(matchObject):
    return "{0:0=3d}".format(int(matchObject) + 1)

try:

    a = input("Enter Session")

    p = r'2([0-9]{3})-2'
    p1= re.compile(p)        

    x=add_pages(p1.findall(a)[0])

    p2 = r'2([0-9]{3})-2'+x
    p3 = re.compile(p2)
    l=p3.findall(a)

    if not l:
        raise Exception
    else:
        print("Authenticated")

except Exception as e:
    print("Enter session. Eg. 2019-2020")
```

**Question:** 
So far I have not been able to retrieve a single regex that will validate this input. I did have a look at [backreferencing in regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) but it only solved half my query. I am looking for ways to improve this authentication process. Is there any single regex statement that will check for this constraint? Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: RegEx is notoriously bad at number/calculation stuff. You can extract those numbers by regex, but the comparison should be done by your program itself.

Comment: NOTE: I am aware that this problem can be easily solved by splitting or taking them as 2 separate inputs but the reason I am trying to solve this problem using regex is because I am working on a project that requires extensive use of regex, so I was exploring all its capabilities and decided to do this authentication just by regex approach. I asked this question because I wanted to check whether there exists such a regex that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why regex? Regex is terrible at math. It would be easier to do something like:

```
def check_years(string):
  string = "2011-2012"
  years = string.split("-")

  return int(years[0]) == (int(years[1]) - 1)
```

Comment: Should be `int(years[0]) == int(years[1]) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working on a project that requires extensive use of regex, so I was exploring all its capabilities and decided to do this authentication just by regex approach. I asked this question because I wanted to check whether there exists such a regex that I am not aware of. @SheshankS.

Comment: There is none, you can't do regex and do math in it. you could extract the two years with regex if that's what you want and then compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to get the session year in one input?
I think its better to have two inputs (or just automatically set the session year to be the first year + 1).

I don't know if you're aiming for something bigger and this is just an example but using regex just doesn't seem appropriate for this task to me.

For example you could do this:

```
print("Enter session year")
first_year = int(input("First year: "))
second_year = int(input("Second year: "))

if second_year != (first_year + 1):
    # some validation
else:
    # program continues
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working on a project that requires extensive use of regex, so I was exploring all its capabilities and decided to do this authentication just by regex approach. I asked this question because I wanted to check whether there exists such a regex that I am not aware of.